# Export data from dynamodb with php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to export data from DynamoDB table in some format with PHP?

the concrete use case is that i need to export all data of my tables to a CSV file or to S3 bucket.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest thing for you to do is export using the built in tools:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DataPipelineExportImport.Exporting.html

It will push the data to S3 for you, which you can then use however you want. Do it one-time or on a recurring basis.

Comment: how it the cost comparison when we execute a data pipeline or run a scan and save the data ? And ideas on how to best optimize the export cost?

Answer (score 0):

I change the way to think the things, I decide to export data in a XML file. An easy way. If someone needs the way to export and import data from dynamodb with PHP, let me know and I'll post the code to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Please, how can I do this export with php? A lot of thanks!